# Задача по вычислению площади

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Смотрю видео по ооп на ютубе и там предложили вот такую задачу для самопроверки:

> Объявите класс Rectangle, в котором имеется статический метод,
> вычисляющий площадь прямоугольника. Этот метод принимает два параметра
> (ширину и длинну) , **вызывается в конструкторе для вычисления площади
> конкретного прямоугольника и результат присваивается локальному
> свойству создаваемого экземпляра класса.**

Я накидал немного кода, на что ума хватило) Но я совершенно не понял кусочек задачи, выделенный жирным шрифтом.

Если вас не затруднит, не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, написать как это должно выглядить? По возможности как-нибудь по проще, т.е. без всяких наворотов, т.е. как если бы это писал кто-то моего уровня, а то боюсь я иначе совсем не пойму.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

P.S. Ниже прилагаю начало моего кода:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w   #ширина
        self.h = h   #длинна

    @staticmethod
    def square(w, h):
        wh = w * h     # вычисление площади
```

Comment: может я ошибаюсь, 'результат присваивается локальному свойству создаваемого экземпляра класса.'  результатом должно быть self.wh

Comment: Я тоже не уверен, но yandex сообщил это: свойством называется такой метод класса, работа с которым подобна работе с атрибутом. Для объявления метода свойством необходимо использовать декоратор @property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из выделенного текста можно вынести три вещи:

1. статически метод должен возвращать какое-то значение
2. вызов этого метода должен осуществляться в конструкторе
3. результат вызова должен присвоиться в поле создаваемого экземпляра (self)

   ```
   class Rectangle:

       def __init__(self, w, h):
           self.w = w   #ширина
           self.h = h   #длинна
           self.wh = Rectangle.square(w, h)

       @staticmethod
       def square(w, h):
           return w * h     # вычисление площади
   ```

Answer (score 1):

не уверен, что правильно понял ваше задание, но предложу попробовать следующее:

```
class Rectangle:
        
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w             # ширина
        self.h = h             # длинна

    def __str__(self):
        return  "площадь прямоугольника({}x{}) = {}"\
                .format(self.w, self.h, self.square(self.w, self.h))
        
    @staticmethod
    def square(w, h):
        wh = w * h             # вычисление площади  
        return wh
       

rectangle = Rectangle(2, 3)
print(rectangle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это делается (по-хорошему бы еще проверку на положительность длины и ширины добавить):

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w   #ширина
        self.h = h   #длинна
        self.area = self.calc_area(self.w, self.h)

    @staticmethod
    def calc_area(w, h):
        return  w*h

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.__area

    @area.setter
    def area(self, val):
        self.__area = val
```